# CRUD In Kendo Gird Using AngularJS And ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I developed a web service with ASP.NET WEB API that feeds me in the front which is implemented by angularjs and using kendo UI.

In my grid component of kendo, I consume CRUD of my WS, after each creation of an entity, the grid synchronise automatically there is no problem so far. However, while displaying the id field of the newest entity still missing because it's auto-genrated in my back-end. Is there any good trick to retrieve this id or I have to reconsume my ws to get it. I applied this idea by the way and every thing goes well but i'm not convinced that's the best idea. I tried another alternative that retrieve just the last element in my database through my ws but I feel it's still complex way and i'm pretty sure that there's a better way.

Comment: It is a convention that an entity is created, it should return an id, which you should consume in your gui

Comment: I think you misunderstood my wondering. The id which i have talked about is the one that defined in my back not the generated one at the frontal level.

Comment: why do you generate id on the front end?